# How to prove that sum given by generating function diverges for given value of $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, divergent-series

I have a generating function: $A(x)=\dfrac{3-8x}{1-4x+6x^2-3x^3}$ (also I have a recurrence from which this function is built). I have to prove that sum $\sum\limits_k a_k\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^k$ diverges, where $a_k$ is $k$-th recurrence member.

As far as I found in books standard method for getting asymptotic for $a_k$ is to factor $A(x)$ into simple fractions. But in this case I have complex roots for cubic equation and some unusable coefficients in $\dfrac{A}{x_1-x}+\dfrac{B}{x_2-x}+\dfrac{C}{x_3-x}$. So I wonder if there is some simpler/other method for getting asymptotic or proving divergence.

I've looked on something about 150 members of recurrence using WolframAlpha: members change sign (six members negative, six positive, and so on) and absolute value increases. But this method hardly counts as a proof.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: The sum, if it exists, must simply be $A(\frac43)$.  However noting $A(x)$ has a singularity at $x=1$ implies however the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: @Macavity but $A(x)$ has three singularities and two of them  are complex – how radius of convergence is devised from these singularities?

Comment: @Macavity ok, I believe for the sake of solution it will suffice to say that convergence radius is not greater than $1$ and $\frac{4}{3} > 1$. Now I need to find some book with some theory on the question. Would you mind to copy your comment as an answer that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  The given function has a singularity at $x=1$, so its radius of convergence cannot be larger than $1$.